# How to do sub-routing within the application?

Tags: angular, routes, navigation, router

Probably one of the most un-self-explanatory(?) titles I could come up with, sorry.

***First I should note that's my first time ever dealing with routing.***

My application has a Login page, on success login you navigate to the application itself which has static tabs component and what I try to call sub-routing area.

What I'm trying to achieve display the tabs component only after redirecting from the login page to the application AND have inner app routing as well (within the application component itself)

If I could describe how this COULD be achieved is if I could have two `<router-outlet>`s in my application:

- One for the Login -> App
- And one for the navigation within the app itself

But I guess this is impossible.

I really hope you could understand the issue I'm dealing with and help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: No, it is pretty accurate, you just set another `<router-outlet>` in the second component where you want to manage other routes. That works pretty well actually.

Comment: @AlexBeugnet Is that really possible?? Can you direct me to some docs or example showing how can i achieve that?

Comment: I'll make you an example through a github repo.

Comment: @AlexBeugnet Thank you! I'd really appreciate that :)

Comment: I'm kinda busy atm, should be available within the next hour.

Comment: I have an existing github repo with an example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing This example has a tabbed edit page with a child router outlet. This is from the Pluralsight course on "Angular Routing" here: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-routing/table-of-contents

Comment: I have another example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Modules. This one shows a login page without the navigation info and then uses a child route for a welcome page with navigation info.

Comment: Guess it's all good =)